# insertar en base de datos con php y html

Tags: php, html, bootstrap

Estoy mediant un nav-item (bootstrap) guardando datos en una base de datos usando un archivo de php, pero al momento de guardar los datos se abre el archivo php y quisiera que sólo se ejecutara sin que se abriera, osea, que sólo haga la insersion de datos sin que se abra.

el nav-item de mi archivo:

```
        <ul class="nav flex-column">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">
              <span data-feather="home"></span>
              Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="y.php?valor=0">
              <span data-feather="file"></span>
              Activar
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span data-feather="bar-chart-2"></span>
              Reportes
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span data-feather="layers"></span>
              Operaciones
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

Mi archivo php:

```
<?php include ('functions.php');
$valor=$_GET['valor'];

ejecutarSQLCommand("UPDATE fs SET State='$valor' WHERE Color= 'red'");

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que no refrescar la pagina, durante la insercion de datos, puedes utilizar las funciones ajax que provee jquery
Ejemplo:

```
var ruta="localhost/aplicacion/y.php?valor=0";
$.ajax( 
{ url:  ruta , method:"GET", success:function(data){ alert("agregado!");}
}
);
```

Elabora la ruta de acuerdo a tu caso
Esto puedes ponerlo dentro de una funcion

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function insertar(){
var ruta="localhost/aplicacion/y.php?valor=0";
$.ajax( 
{ url:  ruta , method:"GET"}
);
}
</script>
```

Y para llamar a esta funcion, por ejemplo

```html
  <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href= "#"  onclick="insertar()">
              <span data-feather="file"></span>
              Activar
            </a>
          </li>
```

Comment: Si estas usando bootstrap, seguro tienes incluida la libreria de jquery. Asegurate de incluir el codigo justo debajo de la inclusion de esta libreria